# NGINX return 405 Not Allowed with POST method

Tags: nginx

I have this default.conf:

```
server {
        listen  443 ssl;
        root /etc/nginx/json/;
        server_name    myserver.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/server.key;
        ssl_protocols   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers     HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        location /platform/enabler/iam/token/generate/1.0.0
        {
                alias  /etc/nginx/json/generateToken.json;
        } }
```

calling the API with GET method the response is correct.
calling the API with POST method the response is:

```
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following line to your config to make nginx serve the POST requests with static files:

```
error_page 405 =200 $uri;
```

Comment: in which line of my configuration?

Comment: @sarjaana You can add it inside the `location` block to allow only `/platform/enabler/iam/token/generate/1.0.0` POST request or to the `server` block to allow POST requests globally.

Answer (score 0):

That solution didn't work for me, but what did was the following config (I'm using nginx as reverse proxy and everything dockerized)

```
    location / {
       include /etc/nginx/includes/common_location.conf;
       resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
       set $upstream localhost:4200;
       proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    }

    location = /land {
       include /etc/nginx/includes/common_location.conf;
       proxy_method GET;
       resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
       rewrite ^ https://example.com/land/ break;
    }
```

common_location.conf has the following:

```
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
proxy_set_header    Connection          $http_connection;
```