# 405 not allowed nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, plesk

I just uploaded my angular app into my server on Plesk, the app works just fine and it's based on REST-API. so when I tried to test it I got this error when I send my first POST request

> 405 Not Allowed
> nginx

at first, I got the forbidden page when tried to access the app, so I added this

```
location ^~ /folder{
    allow all;

}
```

this fixed the forbidden page but not 405 Not Allowed
Can this has something to do with that, and if not how can I fix it

Comment: Did it help? As far as I can see this really was a permisison problem, your config fix might work.

Comment: that fixed the forbidden problem but not the 405 not Allowed problem

Comment: There is a good guide on that error here: https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/405-method-not-allowed#:~:text=The%20405%20Method%20Not%20Allowed,method%20for%20the%20requested%20resource. It includes some troubleshooting tips.

Comment: What the message means is that the give method is not valid for the resource, so somehow that URI is not accepting POST requests.

Comment: Well in fact when I try to access that URL which is a PHP file it gets downloaded instead of being executed can this be the problem

Comment: Well, this explains some things. You have to get nginx to forward your request to a php service, like php-fpm. Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx ?

Comment: thank you for your response but that gave me 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: it looks like `location ^~ /folder{
    allow all;

}` was causing the problem when I remove it the app worked for while but then I got the forbidden page

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431038/nginx-return-405-not-allowed-with-post-method/62431969#62431969) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Plesk every section needs to have an index.php and not index.html, so I added and changed index page that I have to index.php and removed the nginx code which was causing the 405 error and now every thing works fine